# Configure a default scenario in MS Health Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework

I am using Microsoft's Health Bot Service to create a healthcare bot.

I have created 2 scenarios and I want one of them to be the one that will kick off when starting a new conversation.

I failed to find anywhere in the Health Bot Service portal how to configure this.

Comment: Did you find my answer below to be helpful? If so, please mark it as answered and I'll close this issue in my support tracker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the bot to start the scenario before the user has interacted with it, that feature isn't currently available since ["before triggering a scenario, the bot waits for initial input from the end user."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/bot_docs/bot-lobby-page#user-intents)

As the Health Bot was just made available to the general public in the last week, that feature may be added in the future, but I'm not sure.

Currently, if a user has initiated a conversation with the bot previously, you can [send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/integrations/proactive).

Otherwise, I'd suggest doing the following to get close to what you're looking for:

1. In Configuration > Conversation > Interactions, change the Automatic welcome to something like, "Say "start scenario" to get started." Obviously, change "start scenario" to whatever makes the most sense for your use case.

Step:

[image]

Result:

[image]

2. Go to Scenarios > Manage and create your "Kick off" scenario

Step:

[image]

[image]

3. Go to Language > Models and make a new model. Use LUIS or RegEx, but make sure that the expression it looks for is the one you told the user to use in step 1. Then, for Intent Mapping, point it to the scenario you created in step 2.

Step:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. 
I hope MS will add that important feature soon.
For now I will implement your suggestion.
Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear! I can update this post if I hear that MS implements this. In the meantime, can you mark this as answered so I can clear it off of my support tracker? Thanks!

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Did MS update this feature or not?